# Docking control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want a lightweight control in MVC2 to dock a number of items to the top of the browser, so it is always visible as the user scrolls down through the main content.  What's the best thing to use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using CSS with fixed position:

```
#top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Then place the controls inside a `<div id="top"></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [fixed positioning in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```
#item
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    right:5px;
}
```